# Xcode documentation gone

Tags: xcode

Just updated to `8.2.1` (through the app store) and now *all my documentation is gone*.
Whether I use the build in documentation browser or Dash (which I prefer) doesn't make a difference; no documentation is shown.

When I open the settings it just shows the *Guides and Sample Code*, shouldn't there be more documentation here anyway?

[image: xcode is wonderful]

I've checked the locations for the docsets (the app itself and my library) but I see some docsets there.

Also seen questions which explain how you can download them manually (from https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex), but that doesn't work. Moreover I think Xcode should just download them automatically, as it was before.

Is there some way to make Xcode just download them again?

Comment: Xcode only shows Components, that are not already installed. (For instance iOS 10.2.x simulator is not shown as it is already installed. What exactly happens if you try to open Window Menu -> Documentation and API Reference?

Comment: But if that's the case...why _does_ it shows the Guides and Sample Code? When I open the docs, it shows a blank page :/

Comment: I correct: It does not show Components, that are downloaded or installed by Xcode by default. It looks the same here.

Comment: I see, well trying a reinstall now